# How to use display instead of visibility in web api mvc project?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing WebApi Project.

In index.cshtml file I try to show and hide div according to button click.
now I am using Visibility hidden and visible . instead of this I need to use display none and show because visibility="hidden" method just hide the div it's not remove the div space .if i show the second div it's comes under the first div.

### My Code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
             <input type="button" value="Hide"  runat="server" onclick="Testing()"/>
             <input type="button" value="Show"  runat="server" onclick="Testing2()"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
         <td>
            <div runat="server" id="InputuploadDivTest" style="visibility:visible">
                @Html.Raw(@TempData["tranresult"])
            </div>
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div runat="server" id="UilDivTest" style="visibility:hidden">
                 @Html.Raw(@TempData["Result"])
            </div> 
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Script Code**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function Testing() 
            {
                document.getElementById("InputuploadDivTest").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("UilDivTest").style.visibility = "hidden";

             }
            function Testing2() {
                document.getElementById("UilDivTest").style.visibility = "visible";
                document.getElementById("InputuploadDivTest").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
</script>
```

How to use display:none and show for my above code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "display:none" to hide the particular div

```
<div runat="server" id="UilDivTest" style="display:none">
             @Html.Raw(@TempData["Result"])
        </div> >
```

You can similarly show this div by :

```
function Testing2() {
           document.getElementById("UilDivTest").style.display = "block"
        }
```

You can also hide a particular div by adding the "display" attribute to it :

```
document.getElementById("UilDivTest").style.display = "none"
```